C# unit test got type conversion error on mocked objects, so how to convert the Moq.Mock type to the wanted type?
We are trying to set up a unit test for a C# controller class, named FunctionController, so the unit test is the class FunctionControllerTests.
To build an instance of the controller under test, we need to call the constructor, and we used the Mock template to generate the required input arguments.
...
    public class FunctionControllerTests
    {
        private FunctionController _controller;

        private Mock<ILogger<FunctionController>> _logger;
        private Mock<IOptions<ApiProjectConfig>> _options;

        public FunctionControllerTests()
        {
            _controller = new FunctionController(
                options: _options, logger: _logger
                );
        }
    }
...

However, the mocking objects got errors of CS1503 saying something like cannot convert from 'Moq.Mock<...IOptions<...ApiProjectConfig>>' to '...IOptions<...ApiProjectConfig>'. So, the input argument failed to convert from the mocked type to the original type.
The FunctionController class uses the logger and options arguments are for logging and service configuration. And our unit test will not need them.
So, we hope to find a way to work around the conversion error and proceed to testing the member functions of this controller class.

Don't you need the underlying type instead of the wrapper Mock<...> instances? So should be:
_controller = new FunctionController(
                options: _options.Object, logger: _logger.Object
                );

